# profiling in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I'm Using Win 8  x64
and setup Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

I run a C# project

and want to run the profiling to my project

when I start profiling It give me

' Profiling started.

Profiling process ID 848 (testing).

'848' is not a valid Process ID.

Profiler stopping.

PRF0025: No data was collected.

Profiling complete. '

I'm new in Profiling

I Google for this problem and just found some tell the problem with WIN 8 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsprofiler/thread/c609d76c-be22-4ffb-858c-73ccab591a78/

but Now  what I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 15):

This will happen when your program quits too soon, before the profiler had a chance to collect any samples.  Perhaps somewhat typical when you kick the tires to see how it works but haven't written any real code yet that can be profiled in a meaningful way.

For very short programs with little actual code, be sure to change the profiling mode.  Use Analyze + Performance Wizard and switch from "sampling" to "instrumentation" mode.  Instrumentation mode slows down the program a great deal but is a lot more accurate for very short programs.

Comment: thanks exactly my program quits too soon, but I wasn't able to change mode as you mentioned

Comment: I had the same problem, It was happening because the program I was profiling was using some DLLs that were not available directly in the folder were the process was initiated. I was setting the `PATH` variable in the Debug project properties page. Making these DLLs available (copying them) solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the process is still running when the profiler starts? Looking at the message about the process ID not being valid, it sounds like the process might have exited before the profiler had a chance to collect anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mode in the "Performance Explorer" window, by right-clicking the project name (it should display "(Sampling)" after the name) and clicking "Properties".
The very first option is the profiling method.

More info on the subject : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264994.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem when I forgot to "run as administrator" Visual Studio before attempting to profile.